# Is there a function that returns $x$ with all repeated prime factors removed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition

Let $x = f_1^{k_1} f_2^{k_2} \cdots f_n^{k_n}$ where $f_i \in \mathbb{P}^+$, $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $f_i \neq f_j \iff i \neq j$. I require a function that returns $x$ with all repeated prime factors removed.

Let us denote that function as $r$ such that $r(x) = f_1 f_2 \cdots f_n$.

I would like to know if there is a standardized function for this operation, or if it is something I need to define myself?

Thanks!

Comment: This is known as $\operatorname{rad}(x)$

Comment: @TravorLZH Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure if this should be a comment, but it seems to me that you have already defined it. That is, decompose $x$ into its prime factorization, and let $r(x)$ be the product of all of $x$'s prime factors once each. Note that we require $x>1$ here

Comment: @IAAW I'm working on writing up a proof, and I'd like to avoid redefining standard terms and functions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer

Comment: @IAAW: You don't require $x>1$ if you adopt the standard convention that the product of the elements of an empty list is $1$ (just as the sum of the elements of an empty list is $0$).